# How many ways are there to give 40 identical beans to 4 children such that each child gets and keeps at least 2 of them?

Tags: combinatorics

I think it's 39 C 3 but just want confirmation

Comment: you mean, each child get at least two? should not the answer be $32 + 4 -1 \choose 4$ using the bars and stars?

Comment: I assume that the beans are identical and each child gets at least $2$. Then $\binom{39}{3}$ is not right. It should be $\binom{35}{3}$.

Answer (score 2):

As the others have said in the comments above, this is solvable via the Stars&Bars method.

Rewording the equation into a more common form, letting $x_1$ be the number of beans the first child gets, $x_2$ be the number of beans the second child gets, etc...: we are asked to find the number of integral solutions to the system of equations:

$$\begin{cases} x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4 = 40\\ 2\leq x_1\\ 2\leq x_2\\ 2\leq x_3\\ 2\leq x_4\end{cases}$$

Our standard formula applies however when it the lower bound is zero for each of the variables.  Thus, make the change of variables: $y_i = x_i-2$, making it so that $0= 2-2\leq x_i-2=y_i$ and

$$\begin{align}y_1+y_2+y_3+y_4 &= (x_1-2)+(x_2-2)+(x_3-2)+(x_4-2) \\ & = (x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4)-8 \\ &= 40-8 \\&= 32\end{align}$$

Thus we have

$$\begin{cases} y_1+y_2+y_3+y_4 = 32\\ 0\leq y_1\\ 0\leq y_2\\ 0\leq y_3\\ 0\leq y_4\end{cases}$$

We can now use our formula from stars and bars to arrive at the solution:  $$\binom{32+4-1}{4-1} = \binom{35}{3}$$

Our change of variable has the same intuitive effect as "Before starting, give each child two beans ahead of time and then count how many ways you can distribute the rest."

---

In general, the number of integral solutions to a system of equations of the form:

$$\begin{cases} x_1+x_2+\dots+x_r = n\\ 0\leq x_1\\ 0\leq x_2\\ \vdots\\ 0\leq x_r\end{cases}$$

is: $$\binom{n+r-1}{r-1}$$

To see this, consider arrangements of $n$ $\star$'s and $(r-1)$ $\mid$'s (E.g. $\star\star\mid\star\star\star\mid\mid\star\dots$).  The number of stars to the left of the furthest left bar will be the value of $x_1$.  The number of stars inbetween the first and second bar will be the value of $x_2$.  In general the number of stars inbetween the $(i-1)^{st}$ and $i^{th}$ bars will be the value of $x_i$ (zero is an allowable amount).  It should be easy to convince yourself that each different arrangement of stars and bars will lead to a different solution of the system of equations, and that every solution has some arrangement of stars and bars to match.  I.e. that this is a bijection.

Thus the number of solutions to the system is the number of combinations, which is $\binom{n+r-1}{r-1}$

Answer (score 0):

Computer simulation is super easy.  Just run nested loops from $2$ to $34$ (To be a "winner", $2$ is the minimum # of beans each child can have and $34$ is the maximum).  The correct answer of $6545$ quickly results.  I called the nested loops a, b, c, and d and just check if a+b+c+d = $40$.  Doesn't get much simpler than that.

A mildly interesting variation is if you "lift" the constraint that each child have $2$ beans minimum (allowing $1$ or even $0$), the # of possible combinations almost doubles (from $6545$ to $12341$).

Just FYI, if each child gets $1$ bean minimum, then the answer is $9139$.

Note that computer simulation allows "playing" with the numbers without having to rethink the algorithm.  I can check anywhere from $0$ to $9$ beans min per child easily just by changing $1$ character in the code.

Obviously if $10$ beans each is the minimum then there is only $1$ solution.