# How many integer solutions does the following system have:

Tags: combinatorics

> $x_1 + x_2 + x_3 = 15$
> $x_1 \ge 5$
> $x_2 \ge 4$
> $x_3 \ge 0$

Comment: That's certainly small enough to count by brute force.  Try that first.  If you don't see a pattern to generalize, come back.

Comment: That too 2 links. And this type of problem is very popular, so try searching this site for similar problems.

Comment: Using Mathematica, `Solve[{x1 + x2 + x3 == 15, x1 >= 5, x2 >= 4, x3 >= 0}, {x1, x2, x3}, Integers] // Length` returns `28`

Comment: When you pose a question here, you should include any work you have done on the problem and indicate where you are stuck so that you receive responses that address the specific difficulties you are encountering.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig you are right! i should. Like i said I'm new at this so i didn't really know.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in several other answers, [see for example this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1221868/how-many-ways-are-there-to-give-40-identical-beans-to-4-children-such-that-each/1221901#1221901), this can be solved using stars and bars and a change of variable.

In general, for the system:$\begin{cases} x_1+x_2+\dots+x_r = n\\
0\leq x_1\\
\vdots\\
0\leq x_r\end{cases}$

there are a total of $\binom{n+r-1}{r-1}=\binom{n+r-1}{n}$ number of integer solutions.

Let us make a change of variable so that we have $0\leq$ for each term instead of $5\leq$ and $4\leq$ as you do for $x_1$ and $x_2$.

Let $y_1=x_1-5$ and let $y_2=x_2-4$.  Let $y_3=x_3$.  You have then $y_1+y_2+y_3=x_1+x_2+x_3-5-4=15-5-4=6$.

The question is then how many solutions there are to the system

$\begin{cases}y_1+y_2+y_3=6\\0\leq y_1\\0\leq y_2\\0\leq y_3\end{cases}$

> Using the above formula, there are $\binom{6+3-1}{3-1}=\binom{8}{2}=28$ solutions

Answer (score -1):

**Hint**

Use the method of generating functions and consider coefficient of $x^{15}$ in the product of the following series: $\displaystyle\sum\limits_{n=5}^\infty x^n$, $\displaystyle\sum\limits_{n=4}^\infty x^n$ and $\displaystyle\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty x^n$.

Comment: a bit overkill when stars&bars would suffice